# Find four whole numbers... Is this maths question impossible?

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

I'm helping out my nephew with his 11+ exam revision. We have practice papers but no answers so.

One of the questions is as follows:

> Find four whole numbers whose sum is 400, such that the first number is twice as large as the second, the second number is twice as large as the third, and the third is twice as large as the fourth.

My math gives me:

```
8x + 4x + 2x + x = 15x = 400

400/15 = 26.6666...
```

Which is obviously not a whole number.

Am I missing something basic or is this just an impossible/misleading question?

Comment: If the exam format allows free-form answers, then presumably one is supposed to show that no such numbers exist. Your argument for that is correct.

Comment: I agree with you on this one. But there is no indication that this is a trick question to be questioned. It's a bit frustrating.

Comment: Is this the exact wording of the question? "twice as large" mean 2X but simple variations like "twice larger" or "200% larger" is ambiguous and can mean 3X. (Note: $1 + 3 + 9 + 27 = 40$ divides 400)

Comment: @achillehui I believe the only word I missed was the word "number" after the word "second" (I just edited it in now). Otherwise it is accurate even to the comma.

Comment: You should actually have retranscripted $8x_4+4x_4+2x_4+x_4=400$, but your conclusion is fine.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Why do you say the OP should have used $x_4$ instead of $x$? Of course, $x_4$ is what you get if you begin by giving each of the four numbers a separate, reasonable name.  But if one sees instantly, without writing equations, that the "fourth number" in the problem is essentially the only unknown, then it makes good sense to call it simply $x$. (I generally prefer to take care of trivialities by seeing them and using simplified notation accordingly, rather than getting them from algebraic manipulation.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass: my remark is not about $x_4$ vs $x$, it is about the fact that the doublings go right to left and not left to right. Anyway $x_4$ is not extra luxury as it clearly states what number $x$ stands for: first or last ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for the clarification.  I'm not sure the order of terms is worth any attention, but, since the question was in part a pedagogical one (explaining to the OP's nephew), you're probably right that keeping the notation close to the ordinary intuition of the question is probably useful.

Comment: alright I updated the order...

Comment: People who write these things do sometimes make mistakes.  I'm suspecting the person was thinking x + x + 2x + 4x = 8x =400 so x = 50 and simply worded it completely wrong.  ... you are right.  The question is wrong.  They made a mistake.  You are doubting yourself.  Stop. Because you are right and the question was wrong.  Nothing more needs be done, does it?